# Apportable: Compilation fail for 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView' and 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView'

Tags: ios, sdk, mapkit, apportable

I'm compiling my source code and it just terminates without running the app.
This is the log I get:

```
Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.app4u.portaldorugby/PortalDoRugbyFeed/libPortalDoRugbyFeed.a(MapViewController.m.o):/Users/gringo/Desktop/PORTAL - 2014-02-20/Portal/PortalDoRugbyFeed/Native/MapViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_17: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView'

Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.app4u.portaldorugby/PortalDoRugbyFeed/libPortalDoRugbyFeed.a(MapViewController.m.o):/Users/gringo/Desktop/PORTAL - 2014-02-20/Portal/PortalDoRugbyFeed/Native/MapViewController.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_77: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView'

scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/PortalDoRugbyFeed/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So it's mainly a problem with MKPinAnnotationView and MKMapView.
If I'm not mistaken the 'Starter' pack deals with this.

Can anyone help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

We have no support for MapKit at this time, and it's also not currently on our roadmap. It may be possible to use [BridgeKit](http://docs.apportable.com/using-java.html#wrapping-java-methods) to use the native Android mapping APIs and achieve what you want.

Comment: what if I use Google Maps? Do you acknowledge it could compile?

Comment: you could use bridgekit to create objc classes and methods that call into android's mapview class or similar.